# How to Customize Windows Explorer Toolbar

Tags: windows-8, registry

I am trying to customize (add my own menus to the) Windows Explorer toolbar. From web I came to know that it is possible to that by editing the registry.  So I changed the owner of

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksItemsSelected\]
```

and set permissions as full control to me.  Adding keys to the above registry didn’t work for me in windows 7 and 8 as well.

I installed the tools “ CustomExplorerToolbar.exe" and “ExplorerToolbarEditor.exe”  that worked in windows 7 but not in windows 8. Also using that tool I can only add existing menus but not create new one.

So I did the technique as described below,
 I created a shell in commandstore.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\command1]
```

And called that in,

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksItemsSelected\]
@=”command1”
```

The above method worked for me in windows 7, But it is not working in windows 8. Is there any method to implement that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the Win8 explorer uses the ribbon, so those tweaks don't work any longer. Also this question belongs to superuser.com, so **I voted to migrate it to superuser.com**

Comment: Wish there was an answer to this question which belongs here. Have you got further with it?